Is each iOS push notification allocated a separate 30 seconds processing time, if many are received one after another?
Apple documentation states:

As soon as you finish processing the notification, you must call the block in the handler parameter or your app will be terminated. Your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to process the notification and call the specified completion handler block. In practice, you should call the handler block as soon as you are done processing the notification.

Say an app receives four notifications one after another with an interval of one second or a bit less, is each notification callback given 30 seconds separately or should I handle them all within a single 30 second timeframe? How to handle seemingly simultaneous notifications?

As the docs state: "Your app has up to 30 seconds of wall-clock time to process the notification"  (emphasises mine). So - as I understand it, this is for every notification.

30 seconds is an eternity. And thirty seconds is the time to call the callback, you can still have an hour worth of work queued up as the result.
